# Why I can't create second amd instance in Always Free plan by oraclecloud?

Tags: oracle, instance, oracle-cloud-infrastructure

All of users on Always Free plan can get two micro instances with AMD processor, but when I try to create one more instance (I have one now), Oraclecloud says I exceed free usage limit.
[image]
What's the problem here?

Comment: Please, contact Oracle support. They will answer your question about their product.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend you to check your limits and quotas for the corresponding service You can follow this guide for assistance [Limits by Service](https://docs.oracle.com/en-us/iaas/Content/General/Concepts/servicelimits.htm#Limits) for compute for the specific shape you are looking for.

If you see there is available limits for your tenancy and you still get the service limit exceed error, contact the Oracle cloud support team.